Why do I get so many frame drops on wayland with youtube playback?
I have pretty good hardware but whenever I play youtube videos with hardware acceleration turned on, I causes a lot of frame drops. This issue is specific to wayland as on x11, the playback is smooth. (There are some other issues in x11 so I can't use it.)
The browser is running on native wayland not xwayland. This is the case for both firefox and chromium and other web browsers as well.
I have intel hardware. (cpu and gpu)

I recently switched to Wayland and ran into this issue with Firefox. For me the issue was with VSync as Wayland doesn't allow screen tearing whereas X11 does. I have a couple thousand tabs in Firefox usually and did some testing and found frames dropped more regularly when I had more tabs opened. I would often lose 10+ frames randomly all at once on a video causing a noticeable stutter in playback. X11 has no problems with the exact same firefox session.
in about:config I made the following changes and no longer have significant frame drops on Wayland:
media.ffmpeg.vaapi.enabled=true
media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled=true
widget.wayland.opaque-region.enabled=false
widget.wayland.vsync.enabled=false

I don't use chromium-based browsers regularly and never for video playback so I cannot help with that part but hopefully this at least helps on the firefox side.
